# Question about limit of inverse function

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals, inverse-function

So I was looking for a good way to invert the function $f(x) =\frac{\pi K(\sqrt{1-x^2})}{K(x)}$ where $K(x)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-t^2)(1-x^2t^2)}}dt$ and knowing that $\lim_{x\to0} f(x)=2\ln(\frac{4}{x})$ so inverting the latter function to get $g(x)=\frac{4}{e^{\frac{x}{2}}}$. Therefore shouldn't $\lim_{x\to0}f(g(x))=x$ but when I graph this on desmos I get the opposite instead where it seems $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(g(x))=x$ but when I swap the functions $\lim_{x\to0}g(f(x))=x$ is true. Why is this happening?

Comment: Sorry, but your question doesn't quite make sense. What do you mean by "$\lim_{x\to0}f(g(x))=x$"? Taking the limit of a function as $x$ approaches a point gives you a value (unless the limit doesn't exist). So $\lim_{x\to0}f(g(x))$ is a number (unless it doesn't exist), not a function, i.e. not an expression in $x$.

Comment: The taylor series for $e^x$ get more accurate as x approaches zero in other words the limit as x approaches zero, the taylor series for $e^x$ actually equals $e^x$, same principle

Comment: This is pretty standard. If $y=f(x) $ then $x=\vartheta_{2}^2(e^{-y})/\vartheta_{3}^2(e^{-y})$ where $$\vartheta_{2}(q)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb {Z}} q^{(n+(1/2))^2},\vartheta_{3}(q)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb {Z}} q^{n^2}$$ All this belongs to a difficult theory of theta functions and elliptic integrals.